# htaccess passwort protect and allow from ip

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know there are many questions about this topic, but i didn't found any solution that works.

I try to protect my web directory with htaccess password protection, but allow my local ip.
Somehow this doesn't work. On my local ip there is still password protection. If i use "Satisfy any" then the protection doesn't work at all and it is fully accessable.

```
  <Directory "/srv/www/*">
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0.1 192.168.178.0/8

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Authentication Required"
      AuthUserFile "/srv/www/.htpasswd"
      Require valid-user
      #Satisfy any
  </Directory>
```

So if i understand documentation correctly:

```
Order Deny,Allow
```

First all Deny-rules are applied, and then the Allow-rules.

Comment: This do probably not solve your issue but I think you want `192.168.178.0/24` otherwise you allow `192.0.0.0 - 192.255.255.255`. Did you verify what IP you actually come from (access log)?

Comment: According to access.log the ip is correct. In general /24 the one i want to use, but to make sure to catch almost every range i tried with /8